# How to infer signature of property based on another property type?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
type AnimalType = "dog" | "fish";

interface DogMoveProps {
  legs: number;
}

interface FishMoveProps {
  fins: number;
}

interface Animal {
  type: AnimalType;
  move: (props) => void; // How should this be typed?
}
```

How can I enforce the type of `props` based on the value of `Animal.type` field?

```
const dog: Animal = {
  type: "dog",
  move(props) { // <-- DogMoveProps should be automatically inferred
    // props.legs
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to either 1) introduce a proper inheritance structure; 2) Make one or more of your types generic; or 3) use a discriminated union. From this toy example it's difficult to make a more concrete recommendation.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm looking for how to type the `props` field. The way interfaces are structured is fixed, I cannot change them.

Comment: Well, at least you seem to be able to change the `Animal` type, since that's where you're going to type your `props` parameter. Could be as simple as saying `type Animal = { type: 'dog'; move: (props: DogMoveProps) => void; } | { type: 'fish'; move: (props: FishMoveProps) => void; }`, i.e. the discriminated union approach.

Comment: Yes, I can change `Animal` type. Regarding discriminated union, where would that apply - `Animal` or for respective `props` types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a mapping between `AnimalType` and their associated `Props` types, and then use a self-indexing [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to automatically create a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) based on that mapping:

```
type AnimalType = "dog" | "fish";

interface DogMoveProps {
  legs: number;
}

interface FishMoveProps {
  fins: number;
}

type MoveProps = {
  "dog": DogMoveProps;
  "fish": FishMoveProps;
};

type Animal = {
  [K in AnimalType]: {
    type: K,
    move: (props: MoveProps[K]) => void;
  }
}[AnimalType];

const dog: Animal = {
  type: "dog",
  move(props) {
    props.legs
  }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2AVc0C8UBEAJgPYDm+UAPgQGYIDOAFvgNwBQbCcwEATjSgDG0ACJkAssQBuEAAq9iYelADebKFDQRS9AFxQ4AVyQAjPuwC+HLj35DoAMQaNJM+YuVqNdOHoPGzXksOUEgoVzkFJSg8LwIScn0xUgj3JXYNfDomfH0nJlSo+kt2NlDoeGR0GNV1KABtAGkoLlhEVExsAF19OI1y-UaAGjqNJGkIfQAKMCL9Qo8mroBKGIA+KCliBEIMqCsLesqOrEgu0sFiX2AoBP1j6ti6gfiyfBGxiZmi1b6oWY8ADotDo6gcWEA)